# Using JavaScript to measure positions in print view, without Firefox pixel rounding of screen view?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, printing, measure

In Firefox, the exact character width is adjusted (to nearest pixel) for on-screen viewing, but such adjustment does not occur in the print view. This means the number of lines in a paragraph (after wrapping) would differ.

I have some JavaScript that is used to add vertical margins to make two columns line up correctly, within a fixed width div. The alignment is correct on the screen, but not in the printed document.

- I could make the font size and images very large and then use CSS `transform: scale(0.1)` to make the results small again.
- I could have JavaScript separate each line in its own div (after wrapping), which would let me use `white-space: nowrap`.
- Can you suggest something easier with less side-effects? Perhaps a CSS rule I'm not aware of?

I did notice if the user uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> zoom feature, then the problem goes away to some extent.

Comment: Have you tried [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)? Here is [an example](https://davidwalsh.name/flexbox-column).

Comment: I've added `display: flex` on my fixed with container div, but the alignment of its contents still differ between screen and print (Firefox) due to variance in word wrapping. (one word wraps to the third line in printing, but not on screen)